# How can I get rid of empty rows in my spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel sheet that looks similar to the following:

[image]

How can I remove the rows that do not have anything in their columns, so for instance the final result would be:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks! And on a side note, the actual excel sheet has several hundred columns and rows, which is why I did not just go through and manually remove them (I am not the person that created the sheet, am working with something that someone else had provided)

Comment: Couldn't you just sort the rows, and then remove all the empty ones at once? Once that's done, re-sort according to the index column and re-index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data sheet looks exactly as your screenshot does (The rows that contain blanks are empty across all columns), you can try these steps to get rid of the blank rows.

1. Highlight a column that contains blanks.
   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
3. Click **Special**.
4. Select **Blanks**. Click Ok.
   [image]
5. To start deleting the rows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>-</kbd> .
6. Select **Entire Row**.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In Excel all row data are separated by cells, nultiple cells in one single row make a meaning full record (Data).
So to clear up, irrelevant link first you need to define all rows and columns (you can remove this rows and columns after completion of your task.
Steps:

1. Place cursor at A1
2. Insert row
3. Place cursor at A1
4. Insert column
5. Place cursor at A1 and type "Sr#" as column name
6. Type 1,2,3.... upto the end of row. (You can just type 1 in A2, and type 2 in A3 then select A1:A2 and drag the cells to fill the series.
7. Do the same for columns (1,2,3....)
8. Now all of your rows and columns have numeric names.
9. Now select all data and sort it by Column C (That is column name 2)
10. You will get all your filled rows upper and all blank rows below.
11. Delete all blank rows including all Sr. no data and column 1 data.
12. Now again select all data and sort by column Sr.#
13. THats all !!

And you will get your data.

[image]